# How to let COQ write complete proof log?

Tags: coq

I want COQ to log all its subgoals while executing a proof.
The -verbose option of COQC did not give the proper result.

Second, is there an option that let COQ log all elementary tactics used by the auto, intuition, etc. tactics?

Comment: Try the [Info](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.5beta2/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#hevea_default810) command.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Coq (>= 8.7, I think), you can issue

```
Set Ltac Debug.
Set Ltac Batch Debug.
```

and get an extremely verbose log of the tactic execution and the goals being faced.